# Why index is not used when ordering?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
uid bigint NOT NULL,
first_name character varying,
last_name character varying,
email character varying,
login_count integer,
CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (uid)
)
```

with this index:

```
CREATE INDEX users__login_count
ON users
USING btree
(login_count DESC NULLS LAST);
```

The login_count column may consists of NULL values and i need to select all users ordered descending by login_count and need NULLs to be at the end.

Unfortunately this query:

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY login_count DESC LIMIT 30;
```

won't use the index, so NULLs are at the beggining, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is effectively `ORDER BY login_count DESC`*`NULLS FIRST`*`LIMIT 30` as explained [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/queries-order.html). On [this page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/indexes-ordering.html) it describes how an index can satisfy an ordering:

> An index stored in ascending order
>   with nulls first can satisfy either
>   `ORDER BY x ASC NULLS FIRST` or `ORDER BY x DESC NULLS LAST`
>   depending on which direction it is scanned in.

So your index is the same - it can satisfy `ASC NULLS FIRST` and `DESC NULLS LAST`, but your query is `DESC NULLS FIRST`.

Answer (score 2):

How an index is defined does not change the meaning of a query.  In order for the index to be used, the ordering of the index has to match the ordering of the query.

Having said that, it [doesn't appear that MySQL supports](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/) `nulls last`.  Try:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    users
ORDER BY
        case when login_count is null then -1 else login_count end DESC 
LIMIT 30;
```

Comment: maybe a typo, but OP is talking about PostgreSQL, not MySQL.